# Convert ASPX pages to content pages?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, master-pages, content-pages

I am working through the MCTS Training kit book (exam 70-515).  I'm working on a case study practice project based on master pages and themes and the book instructs you to convert ASPX pages to content pages. I've had a look around and can't find anything on this subject, so any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each page do the following - Add an attribute to the <@Page > tag named MasterPageFile="Your MasterPage Path" - Add the following tag - Remove html and head tags and their contents except body tag - Remove the body tags BUT KEEP its contetnts - Remove the form tag - Done

[UseFul Link](http://www.asp.net/Guided-Tour/s19.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I dont have any html tags or form tags in my page, just placeholders, content tags, a text box and a ddl