# Is there a solution to add css template in existing webform which is now having template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, templates

Is there any way to add CSS template for existing webform that has no CSS template added?

My code is listed below, any guidance about how to add CSS template for the form that already exists in the site master will be greatly appreciated:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Linkchecker.WebForm2"
    ValidateRequest="false" EnableViewState="false" EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableSessionState="True"
    EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function finda() {
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            var b = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
            b.value = "";


                        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                            a[i] = a.length.value;


                            if (a[i] == null) {
                                alert("Their is no links");
                            }   
                            else {
                                b.value = b.value + "\r\n\n" + a[i]  ;
                            }

                        }

                        //            window.open("http://www.fillsim.com");
                        window.close();
                     //   window.open("WebForm3.aspx?req=" + b.value);


        }
    </script>
     <script>
         var howLong = 6000;
         t = null;
         function closeMe() {
             t = setTimeout("self.close()", howLong);
         }
   </script>
      <script type = "text/javascript">


     var defaultText = "http://www.example.com";
           function waterMarkText(txt, evt) {
               if (txt.value.length == 0 && evt.type == "blur") {
                   txt.style.color = "red";
                   txt.value = defaultText;
               }
               if (txt.value == defaultText && evt.type == "focus") {
                   txt.style.color = "green";
                   txt.value = "";
               }
       }
</script>

</head>
<body >

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Enter the URL:<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="urltxt" runat="server" Width="402px" Text="http://www.example.com" ForeColor="Gray" onblur = "waterMarkText(this, event);" onfocus = "waterMarkText(this, event);"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRender" runat="server" Text="Page Render" OnClick="btnRender_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:finda();" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btn_createlink" runat="server"
        Text="Create link" OnClick="btn_createlink_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="373px" Width="410px"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="371px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="409px"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;<div class="ab" id="div" runat="server">
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Clear" 
            Width="71px" />
    </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in your `<head runat="server">` section

```
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
   .product-bottom-container 
   {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 10px;
        border-top: 1px solid #C41212;            
        background-color: #ECECEC;

   }
</script>
```

Combinding it

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Linkchecker.WebForm2"
    ValidateRequest="false" EnableViewState="false" EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableSessionState="True"
    EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

### Edit 1

**Here is a link how to add master page in an existing page**
[How to assign a master page to a existing .aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273368/how-to-assign-a-master-page-to-a-existing-aspx-page)

Comment: i have already copy all those css tag links from site master to webform2 which is not having template i forget to add master page in webform2 but now how can i do  @shekhar but thanks                                         done this before but all my design content of webform2 gets destroy

Comment: then it says content not found and if i deleted  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    &nbsp;
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

Comment: <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                    &nbsp;
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>     what about this? if i delted then error gots clear  but says content not found and if i add then error occurs what to do?

Comment: what do you exactly want? Want to apply master page on existing page?

Comment: hey shekhar but my content of webform are gone and if add the content of master page then it gives error