# Adding a masterpage to already existing pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I'm wondering how this can be done because I need this for a school project so it is easier to get a translating system done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign a master page to a existing .aspx page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273368/how-to-assign-a-master-page-to-a-existing-aspx-page)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeLIsIw9um0

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Page" prefix of your page, the first line of the .aspx file. And add "MasterPageFile" attribute into it, and choose the Masterpage you want to bind.